# SQL SUM rows in php

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I currently have this SQL statement that works if there is only one row in the table but if there is more than one it doesn't work.

```
$mon = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount)AS `ingame` FROM `players` WHERE `playername` = '$player'")or die(mysql_error());
$money = mysql_fetch_assoc($mon);
$moneyingame = $amount['ingame'];
```

An example of the table

```
PLAYERNAME AMOUNT
player1    100
player1    100
player2    100
player3    100
```

so when i run the SQL in the code if player1 it should return 200

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time using SQL so just learning.

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` is an aggregate function meaning it works on groups of rows. To use it meaningfully you have to tell SQL what those groups are with a [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS ingame
FROM players
WHERE playername = ?
GROUP BY playername
```

---

I'll also note that [`mysql_query` is deprecated](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should be using [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), or better yet, the database agnostic [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

You also should never put variables directly into the SQL query.  This creates a very common security hole known as a [SQL Injection Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead, use [prepared statements and bind parameters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT SUM(amount) AS ingame
    FROM players 
    WHERE playername = :playername
    GROUP BY playername
");
$sth->execute(array(':playername' => "player1"));
$ingame = $sth->fetchColumn();
```

This is discussed in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/14660).